# Paypal return URL GET instead of POST - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, paypal, get

I'm using paypal for my payments. Everything works fine except for the return URL.
Paypal is returning to my Rails app using POST, how to force him to use GET instead ?

```
def paypal_url(return_path, token_id, pack_id, amount)
    values = {
        business: "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_account}",
        cmd: "_xclick",
        upload: 1,
        return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
        invoice: id,
        amount: amount,
        item_name: Purchase.packs[pack_id].description,
        quantity: 1, # 1 pack
        notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
    }
    "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  end
```

Here is the error

```
Started POST "/users/1" for 90.62.1.250 at 2014-11-06 20:58:46 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/1")
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling PDT? That's returns via GET:

"To use PDT, you must activate PDT and Auto Return in your PayPal account profile. You must also acquire a PDT identity token, which is used in all PDT communication you send to PayPal."

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the answer you might want,
In case you ever want to use the given post request sent instead, add to your routes.rb file (in config)

```
#routes.rb
post "/hook" => "modelname#hook"
```

Then in your model controller, define a new method (named hook) to process the post request

```
#modelname_controller.rb
protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
def hook
  params.permit! # Permits the pay
  status = params[:payment_status]
  if status == "Completed"
    # Process the data
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```